# How do I find the source of an Excel pivot table Σ Value?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel workbook with a pivot table using a data range in another tab as the source.  Locating the source data table is obviously very easy, but there's a calculated field for which I just can't seem to find the source.

If I right-click an item that field (row), and select 'Value field settings', it tells me the source name is **rratio** in this case, and it's summarised by Sum.  The custom name is Ratio.  I cannot find that column name rratio anywhere in my source data.  I honestly have no idea where to start looking for the source.

The item is a Σ Value in my pivot table.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help you since we can't see your pivot table or the source data. Check into "calculated fields" and see if that's what's happening.

Comment: If it is a calculated field then you should be able to view the definition. Does that not help?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've found it:
Under the **Analyze** tab, click **Fields, Items & Sets** then **List Formulas**:

[image]